# $g(x)=xf(x)$, boundedness of $f \implies$ continuity of $g$ at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f$ is bounded on open interval $I$ containing $0$ and that $g(x)=xf(x)$

Show $g$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Show $g$ is continuous at $x=a$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $x=a$.

Comment: The second part is not true. Take $f(x) = 1_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$. Then $f$ is not continuous anywhere, but $g$ is continuous at $a=0$.

Comment: Well people, you have your orders : show, show...!

Comment: Show me my upvote.

Answer (score 3):

$|g(x)-g(0)| = |xf(x)| \leq B |x|$, where $B$ is the bound on $f$. Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{B}$, then $|g(x)-g(0)|  < \epsilon$.

The second part is true only if $a\neq 0$. The function $h$ given by $h(x)= x$ is clearly continuous everywhere. Hence if $f$ is continuous, the product $x \mapsto f(x)h(x)$ is also continuous. If $x \neq 0$, the function $d$ given by $d(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is continuous. Then we have $f(x) = g(x) d(x)$. Hence if $g$ is continuous at $a \neq 0$, then the product $f$ is also continuous at $a$.